# Type safety : Unchecked cast and Generics

Tags: java, generics, dictionary, casting, type-safety

I have a very simple map

```
private Map<String,T> map = Collections.synchronizedSortedMap(new TreeMap<String,T>());
```

I would like to define the following method

```
public T[] values(){
    return (T[])map.values().toArray();
}
```

And obviously, I'm ending up with an unchecked cast problem... My issue is I can't invoke `toArray(new T[size])`.

What should I do to avoid this warning (wihtout using @SuppressedWarning)

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you do call toArray(new T[size])??.

Comment: In Java you cannot create a generic array of T => your code won't compile

Comment: That will crash the calling code at runtime, since toArray() itself returns an Object[] array and the generic cast is a noop.

Answer (score 4):

Avoid arrays. Return `List<T>`.

Arrays are necessary basic building blocks, however they are quite weird in the type system. It's better to avoid them in APIs. Almost anywhere an array can be replaced by an ArrayList. Performance is same.

Comment: Yes, arrays are like strings.  Sometimes they're treated like primitives and sometimes they're treated as collections.  Better off going with a real collection.

Answer (score 1):

> What should I do to avoid this warning
>   (wihtout using @SuppressedWarning)

This warning is the last thing you should be worried about. The bigger problem is that when this gets returned to someone that expects an array with a particular class, this is going to crash with a `ClassCastException`.

Because arrays in Java contain a reference to their component class at runtime, it is impossible to construct such an array without knowing the class. Either have the user pass in something with will allow you to get the class object for the class `T`, or you will just have to return an `Object[]`

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I can think of is to create a constructor for your class that accepts an array of type T (i. e. a T[] argument).  The user of your class is expected to supply a size zero array.  You can then use this array to make a toArray(T[]) call.

Comment: i could not find a way to have the user supply a T.class object in the constructor because there does not seem to be a way to construct a zero size array from the class instance without running into the same unchecked cast exception.

Comment: You can construct an array using reflection with `Array.newInstance()`. Sure, it will still have a warning; but it will not crash with a class cast exception.

Answer (score 0):

To get an array of a generic type you have to pass a Class object to your method, otherwise it will return an array of type Object[].

```
public T[] values(Class<T> cl){
    return (T[])map.values().toArray((T[])Array.newInstance(cl,0));
}
```

You still need to use SuppressdWarning for this code, but it wont throw at runtime. Also if you need it to implement the collection.values() you have to pass the class in your ctor. Arrays and Generics just don't mix well, which is why you should prefer to use collections.